# "No CurrentSessionContext configured" when application try perform a query in the database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-orm

In my current spring-boot project, when I try do a query in the database, through this method from my dao class (it's the unique I used in this step of the development):

```
public class Dao<E extends Model> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    ...

    @Transactional
    public E findByField(String field, String value) {
        return (E) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from "+clazz.getSimpleName()+" where "+field+" = :data").setParameter("data", value).uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1012)
        at org.store.generic.persistence.Dao.findByField(Dao.java:47)
        at org.store.generic.persistence.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac46d9f5.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
        at org.store.model.usuario.UsuarioDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$426a101d.findByField(<generated>)
        at org.store.security.AcessoService.loadUserByUsername(AcessoService.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

this method is called from this service class:

```
@Component
public class AcessoService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuario;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario account = (Usuario) usuario.findByField("login", username);

    if(account==null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
    else if (account.getRole().isEmpty())
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");

    List<Permission> lista = new ArrayList<Permission>();
    int max = account.getRole().size();
    for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        int max2 = account.getRole().get(i).getPermission().size();
        for(int j=0; j<max2; j++)
            lista.add(account.getRole().get(i).getPermission().get(j));
    }

    boolean accountIsEnabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(account.getLogin(), account.getSenha(), accountIsEnabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(lista));
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
# jdbc.X
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mystore?charSet=LATIN1
spring.datasource.username=klebermo
spring.datasource.password=123

# hibernate.X
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

and I have this configuration class to set the sessionFactory bean:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

anyone can see what I am missing here?

Comment: where are you reading in your application.properties file for the database session? add that code please

Comment: @Aeseir the application.properties is read by the spring-boot when I start the application.

Comment: Oops missed the boot part. Do you have any other config files for your hibernate? Coz this issue usually revolves around thread, i can give you generic answer based on XML mappings that are used that fix this.

Comment: @Aeseir No, the hibernate is configured only with the application.properties and the class HibernateCOnfig above.

Comment: If you have additional `persistence.xml` and/or `hibernate.cfg.xml`/`hibernate.properties`  files please add them. Is there a reason why you are still using the `SessionFactory`? There is nothing in there that cannot be done with a `EntityManager` instead saves yuo the hassle of configuring a additional `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean`. I also assume you are letting Spring Boot configure your `EntityManagerFactory` and not that you are also hacking around to configure that as well???

Comment: @M.Deinum no, i don't have any additional persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml/hibernate.properties in my project. and yes, I am letting spring-boot configure my EntityManagerFactory. I am using SessionFactory because it's more easy to persist / update or delete an entity.

Comment: It is as easy with an `EntityManager` as with a `Session`. So I don't really see that benefit. `EntityManager.persist`/`EntityManager.merge` instead of `Session.save`\`Session.update`. It doesn't make a difference, heck internally for hibernate it does the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then after more searches I finally find a solution for this problem. I solvw this adding this method to my Dao class:

```
public Session getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

and changing the call:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

in the methods for this:

```
getSessionFactory()
```

**UPDATE**

another solution I found it's use

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
```

and

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

in my dao class, and in each one of the methods, use something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(E object) {
    getEntityManager().persist(object);
}
```

Comment: That isn't a solution and potentially dangerous as you are opening unmanaged sessions spring doesn't manage those and they remain open. When a session is open a database connection is also open, this "solution" can (and will) lead to connection pool starvation and transaction issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum I try another way using EntityManager like you suggest. Is this a better solution by comparison to the previous one?

Comment: There is no real definitive answer to that I would say. I general if you can do with a `EntityManager` if you really need to use Hibernate specific features first try to see if it can be done with an `Entitymanager` else switch to plain hibernate. But at the moment there is nothing in there that requires dedicated hibernate access. Currently it only complicates things.